# JPM [err] Failed to find Java VM

Tags: java, virtual-machine

When i run execute jpm in Win7 command prompt > jpm then i got this error an  popup and "[err] Failed to find Java VM" error message in command line.

[image: Fail to find Java VM Image]

Before that, i'm face configure issue on Blade CLI, I read some post suggest I uninstall all JDK7 and reinstall JDK8 in my develop laptop.

This is my **JAVA_HOME** variable

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

This is my **PATH** variable

```
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\instantclient_12_1;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Users\admin\.jpm\windows\bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\IDE\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm;%NPM_PACKAGES%;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;
```

This is my node js version, > node -v

**v6.11.2**

I have run the **npm install jpm --global** successful.

Answer (score 2):

This issue will occur in case of 32 bit / 64 bit incompatibility.

Both your JVM and the application which you  want to run (In this case its JPM) should have the same binary architecture, either 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue once, in my case issue JAVA version was updated automatically, to fix that, I just reset JAVA home to new JDK and issue was fixed.

I hope it will helpful for users, facing issue because of JAVA update.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following folder and edit the *.ini* files.

```
C:\Users\Frank Hobbs\.jpm\windows\bin
```

Add the following attribute. Adjust according to the location of your jvm install folder.

```
vm.location=c:\pkg\java\jdk-11.0.12+7\bin\server\jvm.dll
```